# Will this method delete other people's keychain data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am using the following code to remove saved keychain data from my App.

```
        for (id secclass in @[
                              (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                              (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                              (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,
                              (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                              (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          secclass, (__bridge id)kSecClass,
                                          nil];

            SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query);
        }
```

This works well, but I'm not sure if this deletes keychain data for other apps,sites,ect..

I don't think it does, but I am not too sure. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it did, that would be a huge security problem.

(It doesn't. You're fine.)

Comment: KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:Key accessGroup:nil];
        [keychainItem resetKeychainItem]; I actually found this method. This should be safe as well, right? I'm accepting your answer btw.

Comment: Yes, iOS limits what is accessible by each app.